# jQuery img relative path / src using ~

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, image, relative-path, tilde

I am working on VS2010 asp.net MVC project and changing dynamically an image/icon with the following jQuery call.

```
<div class="icon-button"><img src="~/Images/Umark_Icon.png" class="image-class" /></div>


<script>
$(document).on("click", ".iconl-button", function () {
       $(this).find('img').attr("src", "~/Images/Mark_Icon.png");
 });
</script>
```

OR instead I also tried

```
$(this).html('<img src="~/Images/Mark_Icon.png" class="image-class"/>');
```

If image src or the whole image replaced  with relative path with "~/image_path" it does not work with the tilde.

It works only with "../image_path".

It does not work with  "../../image_path" which I believe, but not sure, is due to the image folder depth.

Finally, I want it to work work with the "~/" option which I believe is the most appropriate for the case.

Please any comments, suggestions and demos on the topic would be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the intent of `~/`? Where is the resource relative to your current path?

Comment: @Nucleon If I correctly understand your question the resource is "../../Images/Mark_Icon.png" relative to my current path.

Comment: So to be clear, the URL that someone would see that snippet is it at something like http://yourdomain.com/foo/bar/ and the image is located at http://yourdomain.com/Images/Mark_Icon.png? Relative paths in the browser are based off URLs, not actual file paths. If my example URLs above are correct then "../../Images/Mark_Icon.png" is valid and will work.

Comment: @Nucleon yes it does work, though when on the localhost the path is "../../Images/Mark_Icon.png" but when on the DEV server it changes to "../Images/Mark_Icon.png" and that is what I am trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

`~/` is not a valid URL path. Paths either need to be absolute or relative URLs in order to function in an image tag. You have the following options to my knowledge:

`/foo` - relative to root of host

`foo` or `./foo` - relative to current URL

`//host.com/foo` or `protocol://host.com/foo` - absolute URL

http://url.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ImageURL = '<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Mark_Icon.png")%>';
 $(this).find('img').attr('src', ImageURL );
```

Comment: I am sorry may be I was not clear enough, but I am looking for a jQuery solution, and more importantly no server calls that will lead to a post back. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it does not work in my case for some reason.

Comment: What does it do ? What's the link that you get when you run this ?

Comment: It breaks in run-time somewhere ...elem.setAttribute( name, value + "" );... in the jquery-1.8.3.js and displays the following error message "htmlfile: Invalid argument."

Comment: Try now...Updated answer

Comment: It gives the exact same error message and if I hit Continue button (to continue in debug mode) everything works accordingly but the picture does not change.

Comment: When the picture doesn't change, what's the url it's poiting to at that time

Comment: That is what it is pointing to.<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Mark_Icon.png")%>